# Laravel keeps redirect itself

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing website in localhost

If the links is

```
   http://localhost:12345/laravel/lala/bank/
```

it will redirect itself to

```
   http://localhost:12345/bank
```

but it will work fine without '/'

```
   http://localhost:12345/laravel/lala/bank
```

i try to configure at routes.php but it seems useless

Comment: Can you show us your `routes.php` file?

Answer (score 3):

Routes **aren't the culprit** here, it's likely something in your .htaccess. Without seeing it, I guess it's this line (default .htaccess coming in a fresh Laravel install)

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Judging by your url, looks like you have the project in a subdirectory:

```
   http://localhost:12345/laravel/lala/bank/
```

Try adding a

```
RewriteBase /laravel/lala/
```

in your .htaccess. It should look like this now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /laravel/lala/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

<sub>It happened to me twice, one I solved it like this, the other I went lazy and just commented that line out (`#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`) :D, both worked.</sub>